# Area of reference to find magnetic field inside a (dis)charging capacitor

Tags: electromagnetism, capacitance, maxwell-equations, electromagnetic-induction

Faraday's law of induction can be expanded:$$V=-N\frac{d(BA)}{dt}$$ and for a circuit which creates an area between the wires if that area doesn't change then it becomes $$V=-N\frac{dB}{dt}A$$ The area of the formula is well defined. Suppose a capacitor is being (dis)charged during the (dis)charge a magnetic field is created inside the capacitor. What I don't get is what does the electric flux mean in the formula, of which area do we find $d(EA)/dt$ in order to get the magnetic field?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're asking about the Ampere-Maxwell Law,
$$ \oint_{\Gamma}{\mathbf{B}\cdot\,d\mathbf{l}} = \mu_0\int_\mathcal{S}{\mathbf{J}\cdot\,d\mathbf{a}} + \mu_0\epsilon_0\,\frac{d}{dt}\int_\mathcal{S}{\mathbf{E}\cdot\,d\mathbf{a}}. \tag{1}$$
Here, $\Gamma$ is a fixed closed loop in space and $\mathcal{S}$ is *any* surface bounded by $\Gamma$. So, yes, we do have some freedom in choosing the surface through which to calculate the flux of $\mathbf{J}$ and $\mathbf{E}$.

The point is that the RHS of Eq. $(1)$ is the same, regardless of which surface we choose (so long as it is still bounded by the loop $\Gamma$). This is because the combination $\mathbf{J} + \epsilon_0\frac{\partial \mathbf{E}}{\partial t}$ is divergenceless (see end of post), as we can quickly show using the continuity equation and Gauss's Law:
$$
\begin{split}
 \nabla\cdot\left(\mathbf{J} + \epsilon_0\frac{\partial \mathbf{E}}{\partial t}\right) &= \nabla\cdot\mathbf{J} + \epsilon_0\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(\nabla\cdot\mathbf{E}\right) \\
&= -\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} = 0.
\end{split}
$$
(Alternatively, we could have noted that $\mathbf{J} + \epsilon_0\frac{\partial \mathbf{E}}{\partial t}$ is the curl of $\mathbf{B}/\mu_0$, and the divergence of a curl is always zero.)

**Theorem**: Let a vector field $\mathbf{A}$ be divergenceless. Then for a given loop $\Gamma$, the flux of $\mathbf{A}$ is the same through *any* surface bounded by $\Gamma$.

**Proof**:
Call $C_1$ the flux of $\mathbf{A}$ out of a surface $\mathcal{S}_1$ bounded by $\Gamma$ and $C_2$ its flux through a second surface $\mathcal{S}_2$, also bounded by $\Gamma$. The flux of $\mathbf{A}$ out of the closed surface formed by $\mathcal{S}_1$ and $\mathcal{S}_2$ is zero (by the Divergence Theorem), so $C_1 = C_2$.

Answer (score 0):

From your description I suspect your confusion arises because
until now you have encountered Faraday's law always in
conjunction with a wire loop or with a coil (made up of
several wire loops).
But this isn't necessary. Faraday's law is independent of any wire.
Actually [Faraday's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday%27s_law_of_induction#Faraday%27s_law) is just a relation between the electric field
$\mathbf E$ and the magnetic field $\mathbf B$.
$$\oint_C \mathbf E\ d\mathbf l = - \frac{d}{dt} \int_A \mathbf B\ d\mathbf A$$
where $C$ is a closed curve enclosing an area $A$.
The integral on the right side is the magnetic flux (or the number of magnetic field lines)
passing through the area $A$.
Notice that this formulation does not mention any wire at all.
But of course, for technical applications with wires it makes sense to choose
the curve $C$ along the wire loop.

And now for your problem with a (dis)charging capacitor.
We have a similar situation like above for the [Ampere-Maxwell law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amp%C3%A8re%27s_circuital_law#Extending_the_original_law:_the_Amp%C3%A8re%E2%80%93Maxwell_equation):
$$\frac{1}{\mu_0}\oint_C \mathbf B\ d\mathbf l =
 I_\text{enclosed} + \epsilon_0 \frac{d}{dt} \int_A \mathbf E\ d\mathbf A$$
The integral on the right side is the electric flux (or the number of electric field lines)
passing through the area $A$.
You can choose any closed curve $C$ you want. But for practical purpose
(calculating the magnetic field inside the capacitor) it will make the most
sense to use a circle or a square parallel to the plates of the capacitor.